# The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am calling the request it self in a base class

```
 @Override
public Single<BaseResponse<D>> call() {
    Single<BaseResponse<D>> singleResponse =  Single.create(emitter -> request().getAsOkHttpResponseAndParsed(typeToken(), new OkHttpResponseAndParsedRequestListener<BaseData<D>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response okHttpResponse, BaseData<D> response) {
            try {
                BaseResponse<D> r = new BaseResponse<D>(okHttpResponse) {
                };
                r.setData(response.getData());
                r.setStatus(response.getStatus());

                emitter.onSuccess(r);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                Log.e("error", "throwable");
                emitter.onError(throwable);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Log.e("error", "error");
            emitter.onError(anError);
        }
    }));

    singleResponse.doOnSubscribe(__ ->
            EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.increment()).
            doFinally(EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource::decrement).subscribe();
    return singleResponse;
}
```

then I have my single observer builder class

```
public class SingleObserverBuilder<T> extends BaseObserverBuilder<T, SingleObserver<T>> {

    private final Consumer<Disposable> disposableConsumer;

    public SingleObserverBuilder(@NonNull Consumer<Disposable> disposableConsumer) {
        this.disposableConsumer = disposableConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleObserver<T> build() {
        return new SingleObserver<T>() {


            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                disposableConsumer.accept(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(T t) {
                if (onSuccessListeners() != null) {
                    for (Consumer<T> onSuccess : onSuccessListeners()) {
                        onSuccess.accept(t);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("error", "base error");
                if (onFailureListeners() != null)
                    for (Consumer<Throwable> onFailure : onFailureListeners()) {
                        onFailure.accept(e);
                    }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and in my base observer fragment I access this single observer

```
public abstract class BaseObserverFragment extends Fragment {

    protected CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    protected <T> SingleObserverBuilder<T> getDefaultSingleObserver(Object tag) {
        SingleObserverBuilder<T> builder = new SingleObserverBuilder<>(disposable -> this.disposable.add(disposable));
        builder.tag(tag).onSuccess(object -> {
            Logger.e(builder.tag().toString(), "onSuccess");
        }).onFailure(throwable -> {
            Log.e("error", "base fragment");

            Logger.e(builder.tag().toString(), "onFailure");
            ErrorLogger.log(getContext(), builder.tag().toString(), throwable);
        });
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if(!disposable.isDisposed()) {
            Log.e("error", "detach");
            disposable.clear();
            disposable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

then in the fragment itself that's how I call api request

```
 viewModel.setAvailabilityStatus(isAvailable)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this.<BaseResponse<ChangeSpAvailabilityResponse>>getDefaultSingleObserver(OperationTag.CHANGE_AVAILABILITY)
            .onSuccess(response -> {

            })
            .onFailure( throwable -> {
                Log.e("error", "last");
                if (throwable instanceof ANError) {
                    Log.e("error", "throwable");
                    if (((ANError) throwable).getErrorCode() == 400) {
                        ((ANError) throwable).getErrorBody();
                        handleChangeAvailabilityResponse(((ANError) throwable).getErrorAsObject(ChangeSpAvailabilityResponse.class));
                    }
                }
            }).build());
}
```

in that api request I wanna handle failure request body and it all work fine, but sometimes I get this error :

> The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the
>   subscribe() method call. Further reading:
>   https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling |
>   com.androidnetworking.error.ANError

and I don't know why or what should I do to handle error

also I have this line

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(throwable -> {
    Log.e("error", throwable.getMessage());
});
```

in my application class

Comment: Could you please share the full StackTrace on github gist?